# How to pass parameters and VM arguments after bundling jar as exe with install4j

Tags: java, windows-installer, install4j

I have used install4J and bundled my jar and files into an exe.
It creates an exe with the name and when double clicked it opens up a swing window, which works as expected.

When this exe was a jar, it used to work in two different ways.

1. Double click, and as there are no `String args[]` it used to open a swing window.
2. Call it via `java -jar test.jar -DFIX_RULES="true" -DTEST="false" C://TestMe C://TestMe2` as here we are passing arguments and `-D` args, it used to run as a service too.

How do I call exe with arguments now? Has any one done this?

Comment: I am not exactly aware of install4J, but if it considers the args than you can execute it like `YourProgram.exe arg1 args arg3` from cmd

Comment: I don't see any other way to pass args. Another option could be changing your code to read args from the env variable.

Comment: Environment variables such as `-D` arguments?

Comment: env vars as the system env. You can set an env var in the system in which you are running the app and your app will read it as `System.getProperty("env_name")`.

Comment: Then I wont be able to pass dynamic arguments right?

Comment: No, in such case you can need to have one env var for the list of args and the number of env vars for each args.

Answer (score 1):

To pass VM parameters to an executable generated by install4j you have to prefix them with `-J`, in your example:

```
your.exe -J-DFIX_RULES=true -J-DTEST=false C://TestMe
```

Comment: The issue in this is, as the exe invokes a main method, based on `-D` i decide whether  to open a swing window or whether to run a simple command, even if I pass this, it always opens a swing window.

Comment: Sorry, you have to remove the quotes, I've edited the answer